# Using ExpressionEngine or Joomla templates inside a pre-existing page?

Tags: codeigniter, joomla, blogs, expressionengine

So I'm new to both Joomla and Expression Engine, and want to know if I can use it like I'd like.  I've already made a full site, and would like to integrate blogging into the site.  The site is on CodeIgniter.

Is there a way that I could create a form template for submitting a post which would then save to my Joomla/CodeIgniter DB.  Then, on a different page, use a different Joomla/CodeIgniter template to display the blog in the form I would like.

Note that this wouldn't necessarily be powered by EE or Joomla.  From what I understand, and from all the examples I've seen, you have to make the html of the entire page inside of their templates.

At worst, if neither work, is there anything I can use to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think EE would be the way to go since as of a few months ago, EE was 100% built on CodeIgnitor. I'm not sure from your question what you are trying to do - but in short, if you install/use EE to power your blog it is going to write to the EE database. That said, you can  embed anything within an EE template (raw PHP or CI), including a form that would post to your existing site database.

There's some talk about this on the EE forums:
http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewthread/74157/